# Is there a way to convert integer to char in CAPL?

Tags: type-conversion, capl

I try to write a integer variable into a file by using the filePutString() function in CAPL. Is there a way to convert the integer into char, since filePutString() only uses chars as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the best way would be to use snprintf.

```
char buffer[100];
int number = 10;
snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer), "Text: %d", number);
```